# Stop refresh page

Tags: php, href, page-refresh

I have this kind of href:

```
 <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?dir=down&key=$keyname\">DOWN</a></td>
```

When I click on the links I lost datas entered before in a form,what is the way to prevent this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: what functionality do you want to achieve. there can be different way to achieve different functionalities you want so please be specific.

Comment: If there is a way to prevent this using Jquery or javascript,but I didn't use them before,any helps?

Comment: You can save the value to cookie, using javascript

Comment: Haven't you done anything in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a cookie:

```
setcookie('savedData' , $whateverYouWantToHaveSaved, time()+60*60*24*7);
```

or use a session

```
session_id();
session_start();
$_SESSION['savedData'] = $whateverYouWantToHaveSaved;
```

Ref:

cookies: http://www.php.net/setcookie

or 

sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

From there you will recall your data via either:

```
$savedData = $_COOKIE['savedData'];
```

or

```
$savedData = $_SESSION['savedData'];
```

The rest you will need to learn on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden textbox inside the form and when you click on the link you call javascript function to set the value of the hidden input-field and that function submits the actual form. After that you could access the hidden input value from PHP.

```
<a href=\"setValue('$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?dir=down&key=$keyname')\">DOWN</a></td>
```